# Convert codes to HTML with CSS style

Tags: vim

I normally use VIM to edit my codes and convert them to HTML by using TOhtml command. The only thing I don't like is that the converted HTML does not have css class style definitions. I am not sure if there is tool to convert codes to HTML with css, or I can use additional tool or command to convert HTML HTML with css?

Comment: I think I got the answer. Type the commman: let html_use_css=1.  Then TOhtml will create a html with css classes.

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question on stack overflow if you figure out a solution on your own.

Comment: You can even accept your own answer. And maybe even get yourself a badge into the bargain. http://stackoverflow.com/badges/14/self-learner

Comment: Related: [How to convert a source code file into HTML?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/792/467) at Vim SE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here I copy my comments as my answer:

Type the command:

```
let html_use_css=1
```

Then

```
:TOhtml
```

it will create a html with css classes. For more information and other options for TOhtml command, you can get help by:

```
:help TOhtml
```

Comment: There should not be a dot after the `:let html_use_css=1`